# Scrapy Project - How do I crawl, scrape and export nested relational data to CSV using - "items and pipelines" with pause and resume switch?

Tags: python, scrapy, export-to-csv

I am trying to get several types of "nested data", cleaning them, and saving them into separate CSV files.

```
 want all data to be saved to separate CSV files as per separate items/pipelines.
 and want to give the output file name, from the URL param variable "CatUrlParam" that was used in the main "Google.py" spider file (The category number).
 Also want to use pause and resume functionality for the same.
 Also please suggest good coding practices, like how do I clean HTML data in items or pipelines sections.
```

Thank you in advance.

> Google.py

```
import re
from urllib.parse import urlsplit
import scrapy
from GoogleBot.GoogleBot.items import GooglebotItem, GooglebotItemTwo

class GoogleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'Google'

start_urls = ['http://Demo.com/index.php']

CatUrlParam = 1 

def parse(self, response):

    item = GooglebotItem()

    item["Main_Page_Items_Cat_No"] = response.css('strong::text').getall()[(self.CatUrlParam-1):self.CatUrlParam]
    item["Main_Page_Items_Cat_Name"] = response.css('.textb tr+ tr td:nth-child(2)::text').getall()[(self.CatUrlParam-1):self.CatUrlParam]
    item["MainCatWise_Comps_Page_Url_List"] = [response.urljoin(response.css('#contant-contant td:nth-child(3) a::attr(href)').getall()[x]) for x in range(len(response.css('#contant-contant td:nth-child(3) a::attr(href)').getall()))][(self.CatUrlParam-1):self.CatUrlParam]
    item["SubCatWise_Indvidual_Page_Url_List"] = [response.urljoin(response.css('#contant-contant td:nth-child(4) a::attr(href)').getall()[x]) for x in range(len(response.css('#contant-contant td:nth-child(4) a::attr(href)').getall()))][(self.CatUrlParam-1):self.CatUrlParam]
    item["Main_Page_Resps_Url"] = [response.url]

    yield item

    for MainCmpPageLink in item["MainCatWise_Comps_Page_Url_List"]:
        yield scrapy.Request(MainCmpPageLink, self.parse_getCompDetailsLink)

    for CompaniesSubCatPageLink in item["SubCatWise_Indvidual_Page_Url_List"]:
        yield scrapy.Request(CompaniesSubCatPageLink, self.parse_getSubCatPageLink)


def parse_getCompDetailsLink(self, response):

    itemTwo = GooglebotItemTwo()

    itemTwo["Cmp_Name_List"] = [re.sub("(\\xa0)", "", response.css('form tr+ tr td:nth-child(1)::text').getall()[x]) for x in range(len(response.css('form tr+ tr td:nth-child(1)::text').getall()))]
    itemTwo["Cmp_Products_Names_List"] = [re.sub(r';', '', response.css('form tr+ tr td:nth-child(2)::text').getall()[x]) for x in range(len(response.css('form tr+ tr td:nth-child(2)::text').getall()))]
    itemTwo["Cmp_Products_Codes_List"] = [response.css('form tr+ tr td:nth-child(3)::text').getall()[x] for x in range(len(response.css('form tr+ tr td:nth-child(3)::text').getall()))]
    itemTwo["Cmp_Cert_Url_List"] = [response.urljoin(response.css('#contant-contant td:nth-child(4) a::attr(href)').getall()[x]) for x in range(len(response.css('#contant-contant td:nth-child(4) a::attr(href)').getall()))]
    itemTwo["Cmp_Prof_Url_List"] = [urlsplit(response.request.url)[0]+'://'+urlsplit(response.request.url)[1]+'/'+urlsplit(x)[2][4:]+'?'+urlsplit(x)[3][:-2] for x in [response.urljoin(response.css('#contant-contant td:nth-child(5) a::attr(href)').getall()[x]) for x in range(len(response.css('#contant-contant td:nth-child(5) a::attr(href)').getall()))]]
    itemTwo["Cmps_Page_Resps_Url"] = [response.url]

    yield itemTwo


    for CmpCertLink in itemTwo["Cmp_Cert_Url_List"]:
        yield scrapy.Request(CmpCertLink, self.parse_getCompCertPageLinkList)

    for CmpProfLink in itemTwo["Cmp_Prof_Url_List"]:
        yield scrapy.Request(CmpProfLink, self.parse_getCompProfPageLinkLIst)

def parse_getCompCertPageLinkList(self, response):

    itemThree = GooglebotItemThree()

    itemThree["Cmp_Cert_Name"] = response.css('font font:nth-child(1) b::text').get()
    itemThree["Cmp_Cert_Phone"] = [[re.split(', ', re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)|(-->)|(\r)|(\n)|(\t)|(\')|(Phone:)', '', re.sub(r'(<BR>)|(<br>)', ', ', re.sub(r';', '/', response.css('#divbody tr+ tr td+ td').getall()[x]))), 3) for x in range(len(response.css('#divbody tr+ tr td+ td').getall()))][0][0] if (([re.split(', ', re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)|(-->)|(\r)|(\n)|(\t)|(\')|(Phone:)', '', re.sub(r'(<BR>)|(<br>)', ', ', re.sub(r';', '/', response.css('#divbody tr+ tr td+ td').getall()[x]))), 3) for x in range(len(response.css('#divbody tr+ tr td+ td').getall()))][0][0]) != '') else 'No PhoneNo in Cert.']
    itemThree["Cmp_Cert_Fax"] = [[re.split(', ', re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)|(-->)|(\r)|(\n)|(\t)|(\')|(Fax:)', '', re.sub(r'(<BR>)|(<br>)', ', ', response.css('#divbody tr+ tr td+ td').getall()[x])), 3) for x in range(len(response.css('#divbody tr+ tr td+ td').getall()))][0][1] if (([re.split(', ', re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)|(-->)|(\r)|(\n)|(\t)|(\')|(Fax:)', '', re.sub(r'(<BR>)|(<br>)', ', ', response.css('#divbody tr+ tr td+ td').getall()[x])), 3) for x in range(len(response.css('#divbody tr+ tr td+ td').getall()))][0][1]) != '') else 'No FaxNo in Cert.']
    itemThree["Cmp_Cert_Email"] = [[re.split(', ', re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)|(-->)|(\r)|(\n)|(\t)|(\')|(Email:)', '', re.sub(r'(<BR>)|(<br>)', ', ', response.css('#divbody tr+ tr td+ td').getall()[x])), 3) for x in range(len(response.css('#divbody tr+ tr td+ td').getall()))][0][2] if (([re.split(', ', re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)|(-->)|(\r)|(\n)|(\t)|(\')|(Email:)', '', re.sub(r'(<BR>)|(<br>)', ', ', response.css('#divbody tr+ tr td+ td').getall()[x])), 3) for x in range(len(response.css('#divbody tr+ tr td+ td').getall()))][0][2]) != '') else 'No EmailID in Cert.']
    itemThree["Cmp_Cert_Web"] = [[re.split(', ', re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)|(-->)|(\r)|(\n)|(\t)|(\')|(Web:)', '', re.sub(r'(<BR>)|(<br>)', ', ', response.css('#divbody tr+ tr td+ td').getall()[x])), 3) for x in range(len(response.css('#divbody tr+ tr td+ td').getall()))][0][3] if (([re.split(', ', re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)|(-->)|(\r)|(\n)|(\t)|(\')|(Web:)', '', re.sub(r'(<BR>)|(<br>)', ', ', response.css('#divbody tr+ tr td+ td').getall()[x])), 3) for x in range(len(response.css('#divbody tr+ tr td+ td').getall()))][0][3]) != '') else 'No WebAdd in Cert.']
    itemThree["Cmp_Cert_Status"] = [[re.split(', ', re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)|(-->)|(\r)|(\n)|(\t)|(\')|(Status:)', '', re.sub(r'(<BR>)|(<br>)', ', ', response.css('#divbody tr+ tr td+ td').getall()[x])), 3) for x in range(len(response.css('#divbody tr+ tr td+ td').getall()))][1][0] if (([re.split(', ', re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)|(-->)|(\r)|(\n)|(\t)|(\')|(Status:)', '', re.sub(r'(<BR>)|(<br>)', ', ', response.css('#divbody tr+ tr td+ td').getall()[x])), 3) for x in range(len(response.css('#divbody tr+ tr td+ td').getall()))][1][0]) != '') else 'No Status in Cert.']
    itemThree["Cmp_Cert_RCMCNo"] = [[re.split(', ', re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)|(-->)|(\r)|(\n)|(\t)|(\')|(RCMC No:)', '', re.sub(r'(<BR>)|(<br>)', ', ', response.css('#divbody tr+ tr td+ td').getall()[x])), 3) for x in range(len(response.css('#divbody tr+ tr td+ td').getall()))][2][0] if (([re.split(', ', re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)|(-->)|(\r)|(\n)|(\t)|(\')|(RCMC No:)', '', re.sub(r'(<BR>)|(<br>)', ', ', response.css('#divbody tr+ tr td+ td').getall()[x])), 3) for x in range(len(response.css('#divbody tr+ tr td+ td').getall()))][2][0]) != '') else 'No RCMCNo in Cert.']
    itemThree["Cmp_Cert_Address"] = [[re.sub(r'(\r)|(\n)|(\t)', '', response.css('#divbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1) font::text').getall()[x]) for x in range(len(response.css('#divbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1) font::text').getall()))][0]+', '+[re.sub(r'(\r)|(\n)|(\t)', '', response.css('#divbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1) font::text').getall()[x]) for x in range(len(response.css('#divbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1) font::text').getall()))][1] if (([re.sub(r'(\r)|(\n)|(\t)', '', response.css('#divbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1) font::text').getall()[x]) for x in range(len(response.css('#divbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1) font::text').getall()))][0]+', '+[re.sub(r'(\r)|(\n)|(\t)', '', response.css('#divbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1) font::text').getall()[x]) for x in range(len(response.css('#divbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1) font::text').getall()))][1]) != '') else 'No Address in Cert.']
    itemThree["Cmp_Cert_Valid_UpTo"] = [[re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)|(-->)|(\r)|(\n)|(\t)|(\')|(is  Registered FIEO Member. Current Membership Valid Upto: )', '', response.css('br+ font').getall()[x]) for x in range(len(response.css('br+ font').getall()))][0] if (([re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)|(-->)|(\r)|(\n)|(\t)|(\')|(is  Registered FIEO Member. Current Membership Valid Upto: )', '', response.css('br+ font').getall()[x]) for x in range(len(response.css('br+ font').getall()))][0]) != '') else 'No Valid UpTo Data in Cert.']
    itemThree["Cmp_Cert_Contact_Person"] = [[re.split(',', re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)|(-->)|(\r)|(\n)|(\t)|(\')|(Contact:)|(Head:)', '', re.sub(r'(<BR>)|(<br>)', ', ', response.css('#divbody tr:nth-child(3) font').getall()[x])), 2) for x in range(len(response.css('#divbody tr:nth-child(3) font').getall()))][0][0] if (([re.split(',', re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)|(-->)|(\r)|(\n)|(\t)|(\')|(Contact:)|(Head:)', '', re.sub(r'(<BR>)|(<br>)', ', ', response.css('#divbody tr:nth-child(3) font').getall()[x])), 2) for x in range(len(response.css('#divbody tr:nth-child(3) font').getall()))][0][0]) != '') else 'No Contact Person Data in Cert.']
    itemThree["Cmp_Cert_Contact_Head"] = [[re.split(',', re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)|(-->)|(\r)|(\n)|(\t)|(\')|(Contact:)|(Head:)', '', re.sub(r'(<BR>)|(<br>)', ', ', response.css('#divbody tr:nth-child(3) font').getall()[x])), 2) for x in range(len(response.css('#divbody tr:nth-child(3) font').getall()))][0][1] if (([re.split(',', re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)|(-->)|(\r)|(\n)|(\t)|(\')|(Contact:)|(Head:)', '', re.sub(r'(<BR>)|(<br>)', ', ', response.css('#divbody tr:nth-child(3) font').getall()[x])), 2) for x in range(len(response.css('#divbody tr:nth-child(3) font').getall()))][0][1]) != '') else 'No Contact Head in Cert.']
    itemThree["Cmp_Cert_Constitution"] = [[response.css('#divbody td td td:nth-child(1) font::text').getall()[x] for x in range(len(response.css('#divbody td td td:nth-child(1) font::text').getall()))][0] if (([response.css('#divbody td td td:nth-child(1) font::text').getall()[x] for x in range(len(response.css('#divbody td td td:nth-child(1) font::text').getall()))][0]) != '') else 'No Constitution in Cert.']
    itemThree["Cmp_Cert_Catagory"] = [[re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)|(-->)|(\r)|(\n)|(\t)|(\')|(Category:)', '', response.xpath('//*[(@id = "divbody")]//tr[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 4) and parent::*)]//td').getall()[x]) for x in range(len(response.xpath('//*[(@id = "divbody")]//tr[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 4) and parent::*)]//td').getall()))][0] if (([re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)|(-->)|(\r)|(\n)|(\t)|(\')|(Category:)', '', response.xpath('//*[(@id = "divbody")]//tr[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 4) and parent::*)]//td').getall()[x]) for x in range(len(response.xpath('//*[(@id = "divbody")]//tr[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 4) and parent::*)]//td').getall()))][0]) != '') else 'No Catagory Data in Cert.']
    itemThree["Cmp_Cert_Products_And_Services"] = [[re.sub(r';', ', ', response.css('tr:nth-child(6) font::text').getall()[x]) for x in range(len(response.css('tr:nth-child(6) font::text').getall()))][1] if (([re.sub(r';', ', ', response.css('tr:nth-child(6) font::text').getall()[x]) for x in range(len(response.css('tr:nth-child(6) font::text').getall()))][1]) != '') else 'No Products and Services in Cert.']
    itemThree["Cmp_Cert_Products_And_Services_Details"] = [x if (x != '' or x != None) else ' No Products and Services Detailed Data in Cert.' for x in [re.sub("(\\r)|(\\n)", "", response.css('#explanation1::text').getall()[x]) for x in range(len(response.css('#explanation1::text').getall())) if (re.sub("(\\r)|(\\n)", "", response.css('#explanation1::text').getall()[x]) != '')]]
    itemThree["Cmps_Cert_Resps_Url"] = response.url

    yield itemThree


def parse_getCompProfPageLinkLIst(self, response):

    itemFour = GooglebotItemFour()

    itemFour["Cmp_Prof_Name"] = response.css('.textb .textb td.textb strong::text').get()
    itemFour["Cmp_Prof_Products_List"] =  [re.sub(r';', ', ', re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)', '', response.css('.textb .textb tr+ tr td:nth-child(1)').getall()[x])) if ((re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)', '', response.css('.textb .textb tr+ tr td:nth-child(1)').getall()[x])) != '') else ' No/Err Profile Products Data' for x in range(len(response.css('.textb .textb tr+ tr td:nth-child(1)').getall()))]
    itemFour["Cmp_Prof_Code_List"] = [str(re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)', '', re.sub(r';', ', ', response.css('.textb .textb tr+ tr td:nth-child(2)').getall()[x]))) if (str(re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)', '', re.sub(r';', ', ', response.css('.textb .textb tr+ tr td:nth-child(2)').getall()[x]))) != '') else ' No/Err Profile Products ITC HS Code Data' for x in range(len(response.css('.textb .textb tr+ tr td:nth-child(2)').getall()))]
    itemFour["Cmps_Prof_Resps_Url"] = response.url

    yield itemFour


def parse_getSubCatPageLink(self, response):

    itemFive = GooglebotItemFive()

    itemFive["SubCat_Code_Number"] = response.css('strong::text').getall()
    itemFive["SubCat_Name"] = [re.sub(r'(<[^>]+>)|(-->)|(\r)|(\n)|(\t)|(\')', '', response.css('tr+ tr td:nth-child(2)').getall()[x]) for x in range(len(response.css('tr+ tr td:nth-child(2)').getall()))]
    itemFive["SubCat_Comps_Page_Url_List"] = [response.urljoin(response.css('#contant-contant td:nth-child(3) a::attr(href)').getall()[i]) if ((response.css('#contant-contant td:nth-child(3) a::attr(href)').getall()[i]) != '') else ' No SubCat_Comps_Page_Url_List Data' for i in range(len(response.css('#contant-contant td:nth-child(3) a::attr(href)').getall()))]
    itemFive["SubCats_SubChapter_Comps_Page_Url_List"] = [response.urljoin(', '.join(re.findall(r'(?:href=")([^"]+)', response.css('tr+ tr td:nth-child(4)').getall()[x]))) if (', '.join(re.findall(r'(?:href=")([^"]+)', (response.css('tr+ tr td:nth-child(4)').getall()[x]))) != '') else ' No SubCats_SubChapter_Comps_Page_Url_List Data' for x in range(len(response.css('tr+ tr td:nth-child(4)').getall()))]
    itemFive["SubCats_Cmps_Page_Resps_Url"] = response.url

    yield itemFive


    for SubCatSubChapCompPageLink in itemFive['SubCats_SubChapter_Comps_Page_Url_List']:
        if ' No SubCats_SubChapter_Comps_Page_Url_List Data' not in SubCatSubChapCompPageLink:
            yield scrapy.Request(SubCatSubChapCompPageLink, self.parse_getSubCatPageLink)

    for SubCatCompPageLink in itemFive['SubCat_Comps_Page_Url_List']:
        yield scrapy.Request(SubCatCompPageLink, self.parse_getCompDetailsLink)
```

> items.py

```
import scrapy


class GooglebotItem(scrapy.Item):
     Main_Page_Items_Cat_No = scrapy.Field()
     Main_Page_Items_Cat_Name = scrapy.Field()
     MainCatWise_Comps_Page_Url_List = scrapy.Field()
     SubCatWise_Indvidual_Page_Url_List = scrapy.Field()
     Main_Page_Resps_Url = scrapy.Field()


class GooglebotItemTwo(scrapy.Item):
    Cmp_Name_List = scrapy.Field()
    Cmp_Products_Names_List = scrapy.Field()
    Cmp_Products_Codes_List = scrapy.Field()
    Cmp_Cert_Url_List = scrapy.Field()
    Cmp_Prof_Url_List = scrapy.Field()
    Cmps_Page_Resps_Url = scrapy.Field()
```

> **Edited -** pipelines.py

```
from itemadapter import ItemAdapter
import pandas as pd
from .spiders.Google import GoogleSpider


class GooglebotPipeline:
    CatUrlParam = GoogleSpider()
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        AllMainPageLinks = {
            "Main_Page_Items_Cat_No": item["Main_Page_Items_Cat_No"],
            "Main_Page_Items_Cat_Name": item["Main_Page_Items_Cat_Name"],
            "MainCatWise_Comps_Page_Url_List": item["MainCatWise_Comps_Page_Url_List"],
            "SubCatWise_Indvidual_Page_Url_List": item["SubCatWise_Indvidual_Page_Url_List"],
            "Main_Page_Resps_Url": item["Main_Page_Resps_Url"]
        }
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(AllMainPageLinks)
        df1.to_csv(f"{self.CatUrlParam.CatUrlParam} - 1 AllMainPageLinks - {self.CatUrlParam.CatUrlParam}.csv", mode='a', index=False, header=False)


class GooglebotPipelineTwo:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        AllCompsLinks = {
            "Cmp_Name_List": item["Cmp_Name_List"],
            "Cmp_Products_Names_List": item["Cmp_Products_Names_List"],
            "Cmp_Products_Codes_List": item["Cmp_Products_Codes_List"],
            "Cmp_Cert_Url_List": item["Cmp_Cert_Url_List"],
            "Cmp_Prof_Url_List": item["Cmp_Prof_Url_List"],
            "Cmps_Page_Resps_Url": item["Cmps_Page_Resps_Url"]
        }
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(AllCompsLinks)
        df2.to_csv(f"{self.CatUrlParam.CatUrlParam} - 2 AllCompsLinks - {self.CatUrlParam.CatUrlParam}.csv", mode='a', index=False, header=False)
```

> settings.py

```
import random


BOT_NAME = 'GoogleBot'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['GoogleBot.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'GoogleBot.spiders'

MY_CUST_UAL = ['Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)',
               'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)',
               'Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html) Chrome/W.X.Y.Z Safari/537.36',
               'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)',
               'Googlebot']
USER_AGENT = random.choice(MY_CUST_UAL)

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
  'Accept-Language': 'en',
}

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'GoogleBot.pipelines.GooglebotPipeline': 300,
   'GoogleBot.pipelines.GooglebotPipelineTwo': 300       
}
```

> **UPDATED -** Error produced

```
2021-06-27 21:34:52 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://Demo.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2021-06-27 21:34:52 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://Demo.com/Offrings.php> (referer: None)
2021-06-27 21:34:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'MainCatWise_Comps_Page_Url_List': ['http://Demo.com/search.php?stype=Like&searchStringProducts=01'],
 'Main_Page_Items_Cat_Name': ['CAT ONE'],
 'Main_Page_Items_Cat_No': ['01'],
 'Main_Page_Resps_Url': ['http://Demo.com/Offrings.php'],
 'SubCatWise_Indvidual_Page_Url_List': ['http://Demo.com/BrowseBuyersbyCatagory.php?groupID=01']}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 662, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 150, in f
    return deferred_from_coro(coro_f(*coro_args, **coro_kwargs))
  File "E:\SFT\EDU\PROJ\EXP 30\New folder\GoogleBot\GoogleBot\pipelines.py", line 36, in process_item
    "Cmp_Name_List": item["Cmp_Name_List"],
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
2021-06-27 21:34:54 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://Demo.com/search.php?stype=Like&searchStringProducts=01> (referer: http://Demo.com/Offrings.php)

2021-06-27 21:34:54 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing
{'Cmp_Cert_Url_List': ['http://Demo.com/certificateview.php?num=1', 'http://Demo.com/certificateview.php?num=2', ... TOTAL URLS 23, 'http://Demo.com/certificateview.php?num=23'],
 'Cmp_Name_List': ['COMPANY 1', 'COMPANY 2', ... TOTAL NAMES 23, 'COMPANY 23'],
 'Cmp_Products_Codes_List': ['NUM 1', 'NUM 2', ... TOTAL NUMBERS 23, 'NUM 23'],
 'Cmp_Products_Names_List': ['1', '2', ... TOTAL ITEMS 23, '23'],
 'Cmp_Prof_Url_List': ['http://Demo.com/prof.php?id=1', 'http://Demo.com/prof.php?id=2', ... TOTAL ITEMS 23, 'http://Demo.com/prof.php?id=23'],
 'Cmps_Page_Resps_Url': ['http://Demo.com/search.php?stype=Like&searchStringProducts=01']
 }
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 662, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 150, in f
    return deferred_from_coro(coro_f(*coro_args, **coro_kwargs))
  File "E:\SFT\EDU\PROJ\EXP 30\New folder\GoogleBot\GoogleBot\pipelines.py", line 11, in process_item
    "Main_Page_Items_Cat_No": item["Main_Page_Items_Cat_No"],
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\site-packages\scrapy\item.py", line 94, in __getitem__
    return self._values[key]
KeyError: 'Main_Page_Items_Cat_No'
2021-06-27 21:34:54 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-06-27 21:34:54 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1149,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 41513,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 3.079236,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 27, 16, 4, 54, 960780),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 204541,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 3,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/ERROR': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 27, 16, 4, 51, 881544)}
2021-06-27 21:34:54 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

> **Edit Summary**

**Edited - "Pipelines.py" and Updated - "Error Produced" - Yet 2 main errors -** 1) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable,
2) KeyError: 'Main_Page_Items_Cat_No'

Comment: To clarify the reason why this question was closed, it's because it contains ***way*** too much code for a simple problem. You need to create a [MCVE] (emphasis on *minimal* here) that reproduces your problem. If you are still having this problem and need an answer, please use the [edit] link to update your question, following the above-linked guidance.

Answer (score 1):

`FileName1 = open(f"{AllMainPageLinks}.csv", "w")`

You're putting the dictionary with all of its contents into the filename you're creating instead of a normal file name with a path.

Your os gets a bit confused when it tries to open a file with a name `{'Main_Page_Items_Cat_No': ['“Very productive use of my time. I attend these events to help keep up with technological advances and the state of the practice. I often get  information at this event to pass to my team to keep them informed on solutions that we may want to incorporate in our environment.”'], 'Main_Page_Items_Cat_Name': [], 'MainCatWise_Comps_Page_Url_List': [], 'SubCatWise_Indvidual_Page_Url_List': [], 'Main_Page_Resps_Url': ['https://events.idg.com/index.php']}.csv`.

Comment: Edited - "Pipelines.py" and Updated - "Error Produced" - Yet 2 main errors - 1) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable, 2) KeyError: 'Main_Page_Items_Cat_No'